# Would a Python dictionary be the equivalent data structure to a Rexx compound variable?

Tags: python, rexx, oorexx

I'm working on rewriting a lengthy Rexx script into a Python program and I am trying to figure out the best way to emulate the functionality of a Rexx compound variable. Would a dictionary be the best bet? Obviously, a dictionary will behave differently and won't be exactly the same as a compound variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionaries and Rexx stems are both [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  They differ a bit in how they behave.  Rexx's rules are very simple:

1. An array reference is split into the "stem" and the "tail", separated by a single dot.
2. The stem is a variable name, case-independently.  This is the dictionary.
3. The tail is processed to identify an element of the array.  It is split into one or more dot-separated substrings.  Each substring is treated as a variable: if there is a variable with that case-independent name, its value is used instead of its name.  Otherwise the name is uppercased and used.  The string is put back together, dots and all.  This is the key.
4. The array can have a default value, set by `stem. = value`, which applies to all unset elements.

So, the result of a an array reference `stem.tailpart1.tailpart2.tailpart3` in Python is:

```
def evaluate_tail(tail, outer_locals):
   result = []
   for element in tail.split('.'):
      if element in outer_locals:
         result.append(str(outer_locals[element]))
      else:
         result.append(str(element).upper())
   return '.'.join(result)

array_default_value = 4
stem = {'A.B.C': 1, 'A.9.C': 2, 'A..q': 3}
b = 9
d = 'q'

tail1 = 'a.b.c'
tail2 = 'a..b'
tail3 = 'a..d'

stem.get(evaluate_tail(tail1,locals()), array_default_value) # 'stem.a.b.c' >>> stem['A.9.C'] >>> 2
stem.get(evaluate_tail(tail2,locals()), array_default_value) # 'stem.a..b' >>> stem['A..9'] (not found) >>> (default value) >>> 4
stem.get(evaluate_tail(tail3,locals()), array_default_value) # 'stem.a..d' >>> stem['A..q'] >>> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

*Rexx-Stem* variable and *python-dictionaries* are similar but there are differences.
Considder creating a **RexxStem** *class* based on a dictionary

#### Simple Stem expressions

```
a.b
```

can be translated to python as

```
a[b]
```

#### Compound Stem expressions

From my experience

```
a.b.c.d
```

would be translated to python as

```
a[b + '.' + c + '.' + d]
```

Try running the following rexx with your current interpretter and see what you 
get:

```
  a.2.3 = 'qwerty'

  zz = 2'.'3
  say a.zz
```

in some rexx interpreters you would get 'qwerty'. Not sure if that is all

#### Initializing a Stem Variables

in rexx you can initialize a stem variable lic

```
a. = 'abc'
```

Some common uses are

```
no = 0
yes = 1

found. = no

if ... then do
   found.v = yes
end

....

if found.y = yes then do
   ..
end
```

or

```
counts. = 0

do while ...
   if ... then do
       counts.v = counts.v + 1;
   end
end
```

#### Initial Value of a stem variable

Like all Rexx variables, the default/initial value of a variable so the default value of *a.2.3* is **A.2.3**. If you are coming from another language this may seem strange but it can be quite handy in debugging - if a variable name pops up unexpectedly --> you have not initiated. It also means numeric expressions crash if you do not initialize a variable.

This not something you need to implement, just be aware of.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I see now how the two structures differ from each other, I will definitely look into creating a class to emulate that!

Comment: Yes, `a.b.c.d` would be translated to Python as `a[b + '.' + c + '.' + d]`, with the _caveat_ that if `b`, `c`, or `d` aren't set, their values would be "B", "C", and "D" respectively.  That's true for any Rexx variable.

Comment: "`a.2.3 = 'qwerty' ; 
  zz = 2'.'3;
  say a.zz` in some rexx interpreters you would get 'qwerty'. Not sure if that is all"  - Yes, this is correct Rexx behavior.  Any Rexx implementation should produce that result.  `2'.'3` means "concatenate 2, '.', and 3, and assign the result to zz", "a.2.3" means "the element of a named "2.3"', and "a.zz" means "the elemnt of a named with the value of zz".

Comment: "default value of a.2.3 is A.2.3" - More correctly, the default value of any simple variable is its name in uppercase, the tail of any compound variable is the concatenation of all its elements as simple variables with the dots intact, and the value of an unset compound variable is either the default value of the stem, or the uppercased concatenation of the stem and tail with the dot intact if there is no default set.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I am not a Python person but I know what a Dictionary is.</sup>

Depending on how complex the Rexx compound variable is, yes.

`a.b`

...is easily translatable to a dictionary.

`a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h`

...is less easily translatable to a dictionary.  Perhaps a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary.

Comment: I think both cases can be handled via dictionary a.b ==> a[b] and a.b.c ==>a[ b + '.' c] in python